# $ rake db:create rake aborted! cannot load such file -- mysql2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using postgres on a rails app  after switching the working app from sqlite to postgres. When I run rake I get the error cannot load such file -- mysql2. I have never used mysql for this app. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

My gemfile does not include mysql and the database adapter is postgresql

This is the stack trace:

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.1/lib/thinking_sphinx.rb:5:in `require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.1/lib/thinking_sphinx.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.1/lib/thinking-sphinx.rb:1:in `require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.0.1/lib/thinking-sphinx.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.22/lib/bundler.rb:122:in `require'
C:/Users/Rotimi/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Book_Search/book_search/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
C:/Users/Rotimi/My Documents/Aptana Studio 3 Workspace/Book_Search/book_search/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:583:in `raw_load_rakefile'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `block in load_rakefile'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `block in run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.0.3/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:19:in `load'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue is with thinking-sphinx. I assume you've built it with the following options:

./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-pgsql --without-mysql

Also, note that mysql2 is a requirement for thinking-sphinx. See here:

https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx

in particular under installation:

> It’s a gem, so install it like you would any other gem. You will also
>   need to specify the Mysql2 gem as well (this is not an inbuilt
>   dependency because JRuby, when supported, will need something
>   different):
>
> gem 'mysql2',          '0.3.12b4' gem 'thinking-sphinx', '3.0.0' The
>   mysql2 gem is required for connecting to Sphinx, so please include it
>   even when you’re using PostgreSQL for your database.

Comment: if mysql2 is required then that makes so much sense! Thanks. I am in the process of finding mysqllib.dll and copying to the ruby folder so I can install mysql2.

Comment: found libmysql in the connector C download. Put libmysql in ruby/bin and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Remove mysql2 from Gemfile.  Try to get a full stack trace so you can see who is requiring mysql2.  Post the stack trace here.   Specify postgres as your adapter in database.yml.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the gem mysql2 from your gemfile if your using bundler or from environments.rb

Answer (score 0):

Remember to include gem 'mysql2' BEFORE 'flying-sphinx' and 'thinking-sphinx' gems